# Symfony 3 foreign key

Tags: symfony

I have a problem displaying my table, when the foreign key is null the row does not want to be displayed, I do not know how I could solve this problem since the foreign key can be null or not null.
If anyone can show me how to do it, whenever foreign key null or not the should display.

**Edit**

I'm using left join query to join my table to display data,

here my entity

```
class Offers
{
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="Nom", type="string", length=45, nullable=true)
     */
    private $nom;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;
}

class Product
{
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="Product", type="string", length=45, nullable=true)
     */
    private $product;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="cost", type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    private $cost;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var \AppBundle\Entity\Offers
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Offers")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_offers", referencedColumnName="id_offers", nullable=false)
     * })
     */
    private $idoffers;
}
```

So I need, when insert for example in my entity Product, if idOffers is null it should give default value.

Comment: can you please elaborate your problem with your entity  structure that will make it easy

Comment: are you using a left join query with the other table to display data ??

Comment: thanks for reply, I've editing my post

Comment: I don't see where you have nullable foreign keys.

Comment: it's not null, but it can be null during its insertion in the database so if I have to put a default value if null

Comment: Up, please!! help me